# How to reuse static library code which is already linked into a DLL with another C++ application in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking, code-size, microsoft-runtime-library

I'm working on a C++ solution in Visual Studio 2010. I've a DLL file which is using some standard C++ library functions (such as string or file functions). For some portability reasons I have to compile this DLL with `/MT` option, so all required runtime library functions will be linked to the released DLL file.

I've another C++ project which is a windows application, this project also compiles with `/MT` option and generates an standalone exe file. The second project also uses the same standard C++ library functions that are already linked in my DLL (The executable also uses some DLL exported methods).

Now here is my question: Is there any way to tell linker that don't link common runtime functions which already linked to DLL file & don't link these shared parts again in the exe file (e.g. reuse same code for string functions which already linked to my DLL)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Although executable depends on DLL, they can still be considered as separate and stand-alone binary artifacts, each of which should contain required symbols for proper execution.

This is one of the reasons why dynamic linking is preferred. Furthermore, I don't see any problem to link dynamically and redistribute the runtime with your application.

Although *Microsoft Visual C Runtime* is included on most platforms, there are many different versions of it, some of which are **buggy** or/and **break backward compatibility**. Thus, it is always a good idea to distribute the version of `msvcr*.dll` that you know works for sure with your application.